# UINavigationBar Touch

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationbar

I would like to fire an event on touch when a user taps the title of the navigation bar of one of my views.

I'm at a bit of a loss on whether I can access the view of the title of the UINavigationBar in order to wire up a touch event to it.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution I found is a button, I use the following (but I don't know how "legal" it is):

```
UIButton *titleLabelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[titleLabelButton setTitle:@"myTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
titleLabelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44);
titleLabelButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
[titleLabelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapTitleView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabelButton;
```

Put that bit of code where ever you set your title. Then elsewhere I had this to test:

```
- (IBAction)didTapTitleView:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Title tap");
}
```

which logged "Title tap" on the console!

The way I've gone about this may be completely wrong, but might give you an idea on what you can look in to. It's certainly helped me out! There's probably a better way of doing it though.

Comment: Although it's heading in the right direction, this is quite ugly - the font property of UIButton is deprecated, and even with that property the title text looks very different to normal. Why bother with a button? A clear UIView would work better.

Comment: Nothing wrong to go with UILabel.  Just make sure, you set the label.userInteractionEnabled = YES.  If not, the label won't react with touch events.

Answer (score 43):

You can add a gesture recognizer to be a single tap to the title of the navigation controller.
I found that in the navigationBar subviews, the title is the one at index 1, the left button's index is 0 and the right button's index is 2.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *navSingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navSingleTap)];
navSingleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] addGestureRecognizer:navSingleTap];
```

and then implement the following somewhere in your implementation.

```
-(void)navSingleTap
```

So you can use this for a single tap, or you can implement any gesture recognizer you want on that title.

Comment: This works if you don't want to set a custom titleView. (Which I didn't.)

Comment: Is it possible to set a tint colour so it looks a bit more like a button? I've tried `setTintColor` and `setTintAdjustmentMode`, but neither work

Comment: This definitely seems to be the most valid answer.  Thanks~

Comment: I've found that I had to put this in the `viewDidLoad` method to get it to work if I navigate deeper into the storyboard and come back, otherwise all of my navigation bar items were activating it after that.

Comment: Hi ~ @phmagic, I fond that it's only work for topViewController, not secondViewController.Do you know why is that? Does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: While creating a view for this seems to be PITA, but on the other hand, doing this instead is a hack, and might break with future iOS versions. Don't do this if you care about your code.

Answer (score 26):

None of the other answers worked well for me. Rather than add a gesture to an existing subview of the navigationBar, or replace the titleView, I simply added a clear UIView covering a good portion of the navigationBar...

```
- (void) setupNavbarGestureRecognizer {
    // recognise taps on navigation bar to hide
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showHideNavbar)];
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    // create a view which covers most of the tap bar to
    // manage the gestures - if we use the navigation bar
    // it interferes with the nav buttons
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/4, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 44);
    UIView *navBarTapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navBarTapView];
    navBarTapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [navBarTapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [navBarTapView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me so far as well, although I seemed to need to add:[self.navigationController.navigationBar  setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; and I still have inteference with buttons due to variable button names as part of the rest of my application - with there was a consistent way of just attaching touchability to the title (which in my case is a UIImageView)

Comment: aha, I finally got just the title being touchable - here's how: http://pastebin.com/eFwTShhz

Comment: @SamJoseph you should post that solution as an answer

Comment: This one is nice as it does not mess with things like the back button.

Answer (score 9):

The `UINavigationItem` class reference has a [`titleView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView) property, which you can set to your custom `UIView`.

In other words, make a subclass of `UIView` with your touch handlers, and then when you push your navigation item, set that item's `titleView` property to an instance of your subclass.

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I act on that touch, for example - how can I call a method in my overall view controller if the titleView is touched?

Comment: Also, with this approach, my title attribute is lost. Could you explain further?

I've added a touchesBegan handler with a simple NSLog(@"touched"); but it does nothing when the titleView is hit. 

I'm creating an instance of the subclass, and assigning it to the instance of the view I'm about to push, ie view.navigationItem.titleView = mySubclass;

Comment: Your custom `UIView` can have many properties, including a `UILabel` to replace the title, and a `UIViewController` property for the "parent" view controller, which you set when you create an instance of your custom view. Also check that your view has a frame of sufficient size.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest and easiest solution in Swift, just copy/paste and fill in the blanks:

```
let navTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: <#T##AnyObject?#>, action: <#T##Selector#>)
navigationItem.titleView.userInteractionEnabled = true
navigationItem.titleView.addGestureRecognizer(navTapGesture)
```

Be sure to set the `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the `titleView`, its off by default.

Comment: Hello, is it fine if we don't remov the gesture?

Comment: Sure. Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to specify a button as a custom `titleView` because that would mean I can't use the standard title anymore. On the other hand, when adding a tap gesture recognizer to the navigation bar, we have to make sure that it doesn't fire when tapping a bar button.

This solution accomplishes both (to be added to a `UINavigationBar` subclass):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // put in -initWithFrame: if initialized manually
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ft_titleTapped:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *titleView = [self valueForKey:@"titleView"];
    CGRect titleFrame = titleView.frame;
    titleFrame.origin.y = 0; // expand to full height of navBar
    titleFrame.size.height = self.frame.size.height;
    return CGRectContainsPoint(titleFrame, [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self]);
}

- (void)ft_titleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // could add some checks here that the delegate is indeed a navigation controller
        UIViewController<FTViewControllerAdditions> *viewController = (id)[((UINavigationController*)self.delegate) topViewController];
        if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(titleViewTapped:)]) {
            [viewController titleViewTapped:self];
        }
    }
}
```

It automatically sends a `-titleViewTapped:` message to the view controller (if implemented). In a `UITableViewController` subclass you could implement the method like this for a scroll to top feature:

```
- (void)titleViewTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
}
```

**Caution: we're retrieving the title view using the undocumented `-valueForKey:@"titleView"`. It's technically not using a private API but might still fail in a future iOS version!**

Comment: This answer worked for me by overwriting `-[gestureRecognizerShouldBegin]` in a category on UINavigationBar and importing that category into my view controller.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible options:  (Use UILabel)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
UILabel * titleView = [UILabel new];
titleView.text = @"Test";
[titleView sizeToFit];
titleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[titleView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by attaching a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the navigation bar subview that corresponds to the titleView.

As the titleView's index varies depending on how many bar button items there are, it is necessary to iterate through all the navigation bar subviews to find the correct view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addTitleViewTapAction("tapped", numberOfTapsRequired: 3)
  }

  func addTitleViewTapAction(action: Selector, numberOfTapsRequired: Int) {

    if let subviews = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews {
      for subview in subviews {
        // the label title is a subview of UINavigationItemView
        if let _ = subview.subviews.first as? UILabel {
          let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
          gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTapsRequired
          subview.userInteractionEnabled = true
          subview.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @objc func tapped() {

    print("secret tap")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39763117/4187837) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34879397/4187837), I went with the below "functional" approach, I am not sure it is anymore readable, but I prefer it over breaking out of a loop.

```
    if let navTitle = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first(where: {$0.subviews.first is UILabel}) {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTapsRequired
        navTitle.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        navTitle.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
```