# Double Tap UINavigationController navigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app with long data list in the tableView, and I would like to double tap the navigationBar to scroll the UITableView on top of the list (where the search is).

How can I implement that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can also simply tap the status bar and it automatically goes to the top of your tableView. No code needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard gesture for scrolling a tableView to the top is a single tap on the status bar. It's enabled by default see [UIScrollView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW28)

If you really want the navigation bar and you're targeting 3.2 and up I would recommend to attach an UITapGestureRecognizer to the navigationBar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
              initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBarDoubleTap:)];
    tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [navController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
    [tapRecon release];
}

- (void)navigationBarDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
}
```

If you're targeting 3.0 or below it could become a little tricky and is not recommend.

Comment: The standard behaviour is a *single* tap. Not a double tap.

Comment: I was trying to add a tap recognizer for a single-tap.This approach is only viable if you don't have a back button, or rightBarButtonItem. Their click events are overridden by the gesture recognizer.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but Drarok is right, using this method I can't use the back buttons anymore. Is there any way to get these to work again? Help please :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That does not work with buttons in the navBar. I'm sorry I do not see a solution for this problem. Maybe someone else?

Comment: Hmm I'll just make it into a new question and link to this one, don't think people are still reading this one here..

Comment: See my solution (for single tap) that works with buttons in the navBar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21288149/235297

Answer (score 9):

Following up on the answer from tonklon, you can distinguish between the individual items in the navigationBar view by getting its subviews.

The subviews of the navigationBar are:

0  leftbutton,
1  title,
2  rightbutton,

so instead of:

```
[navController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

do this for the title of the navigation bar:

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

Comment: Two problems: 1) the titleView is smaller in height than the navigation bar. 2) the subview index might change if there are multiple left buttons (not tested). Here's an alternate solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21288149/235297